# Can someone explain to me why this nested loop function print this way?

Tags: java, loops, nested

So here is the code that runs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) 
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) 
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}
```

why does it print

> *-**-***-****-*****-******-

instead of

> * _ ** __ *** ___ **** ____ *****_____******______

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.print("-");` is not inside the inner loop. Therefore it's only printed once for each iteration of the outer loop.

This becomes clearer when you indent your code properly :

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) 
{
    for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) 
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.print("-");
}
```

Even if it was inside the inner loop (by adding curly braces), you'd still not get the output you expected, since you'll get one `-` after each `*`.

In order to get the output you expected, you need two inner loops :

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) 
{
    for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) 
        System.out.print("*");
    for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) 
        System.out.print("-");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is because didnt put your `print("-")`  inside any of your inner loops, change your loop to :

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) 
{
    for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) 
        System.out.print("*");
    for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) 
        System.out.print("-");

}
```

and your problem will fix.

Comment: No, that wouldn't print `* _ ** __ *** ___ **** ____ *****_____******______` either. It would print `*-*-*-*-*-*-...`